# NSAttributedString: Is it more expensive to redeclare attributes?

Tags: nsattributedstring

Given this string

`Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet`

And given I want it to be styled like this

```
underlined: 0 - 26 (Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet)
bold: 6 - 21 (Ipsum dolor sit)
red color: 12 - 17 (dolor)
```

Does it matter performance wise if this is declared like this

```
0-6 (Lorem )
underlined

6-12 (Ipsum )
underlined, bold 

12-17 (dolor)
underlined, bold, red color

17-21 ( sit)
underlined, bold

21-26 ( amet)
underlined
```

VS if it is declared like this

```
0-26 (Lorem Ipsum dolor sit)
underlined

6-21 (Ipsum dolor sit)
bold

12-17 (dolor)
red color
```

??

This is a very simplified example of my much more complex attributed string.

I wonder if this matters performance wise either when rendering or when building this string.

Comment: I don't know if latter example is possible(?)

Comment: Latter example shouldn't be possible since italic/bold are inside the same key (`NSFontAttributeName`), so it should overwrite it.

Comment: @Larme true. Bad example! I've updated to use another property to make my question more clear.